# Rails Grouped Collection Select Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form. When a category is selected that does not have any subcategories, the default is **0** when ADDED by the database. But when it's EDITED, the value does not get changed, if no subcategory exists.

**I have a coffee script hiding the subcategory form field if one doesn't exist.**

For example, I may have two categories:

Parts

Accessories

The **Parts** category might have two subcategories like Rims and Tires. But the **Accessories** category might have no subcategories at all.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label "Category" %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:product_category_id, ProductCategory.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :product_subcategory_id, "Subcategory", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:product_subcategory_id, ProductCategory.order(:name), :product_subcategories, :name, :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

I want the value of product_subcategory_id to set to **0** if no subcategory is selected.

**UPDATE**: prodcut_controller.rb

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  if params.has_key?(:product_subcategory_id)
  else
    params[:product_subcategory_id] = 0
  end

  if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
    flash[:success] = "Updated successfully."
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have coffescript hiding the input if the subcategory if one doesn't exist, but I'm not sure if its removing the input from the dom, or just hiding it with css.

Option 1:

If the coffeescript is removing it from the dom, you can add a hidden input:

```
<%= form.hidden_field : product_subcategory_id, value: 0 %>
```

This way rails picks it up on submit and you can handle it in the html vs controller, if thats what you prefer. This will only work if the select is removed from the dom, not hidden.

Option 2:

If the coffeescript is just hiding it with CSS, you could set the default value of the first/selected option to 0.

```
<%= form.select :product_subcategory_id, options_for_select([["", 0], "Foo", "Bar", "Buzz"]) %>
```

You might have to build your options manually instead of using grouped_collection_select if you go with option 2 so you can add the custom default option that defaults to 0.

Option 3:

Handle it in the controller method/service.

```
subcategory_id = params[:product_subcategory_id] ? params[:product_subcategory_id] : 0
```

I hope this helps or gives you some ideas!

EDIT:

Mutating product_params is probably the easiest.

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  product_params[:product_subcategory_id] = 0 unless product_params[:product_subcategory_id]
  if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
    flash[:success] = "Updated successfully."
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

If you dont want to mutate, you can:

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # Similiar to .new, but for updating.
  @product.assign_attributes(product_params)
  # Override the existing subcategory if product_params[:product_subcategory_id] is falsey
  @product.product_subcategory_id = 0 unless product_params[:product_subcategory_id]
  # Save
  if @product.save
    flash[:success] = "Updated successfully."
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Or if you are on Rails 5+ you can set a default with the attributes api.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :product_subcategory_id, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Comment: It does not remove it from the dom, it just doesn't add any options to the select, because there isn't any for the category. Option 2 is not what we want due to it being a dynamically generated data select. Above is my update action. Where would I put this in the controller? I tried a few different way and it won't work. See updated controller above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried mutating and it will not update the existing value of the `product_category_id` unless the category selection has subcategories.  I then tried the second option and when I submit the form, it now gives me a form error saying the product subcategory must exist.

Comment: It seems like when there are no subcategories, it doesn't even SEE that field. Thoughts?